# How do I run a Tensorflow Object Detection API model in iOS?

Tags: ios, tensorflow, neural-network, coreml

I have just trained a model with satisfactory results and I have the frozen_inference_graph.pb . How would I go about running this on iOS? It was trained on SSD Mobilenet V1 if that helps. Optimally I'd like to run it using the GPU (I know the tensorflow API can't do that on iOS), but it would be great to just have it on CPU first.

Answer (score 5):

Support was [just announced](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/announcing-core-ml-support.html) for importing TensorFlow models into Core ML. This is accomplished using [the tfcoreml converter](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml), which should take in your .pb graph and output a Core ML model. From there, you can use this model with Core ML and either take in still images or video frames for processing.

At that point, it's up to you to make sure you're providing the correct input colorspace and size, then extracting and processing the SSD results correctly to get your object classes and bounding boxes.

Comment: If you decide to go this route, CoreMLHelpers has some helper code for doing the non-maximum suppression on the bounding boxes (which was ported from the TF Object Detection API). https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers

Comment: I've recently tried using turicreate, which apple now owns. its incredibly simple to load in an SFrame, split into train/test data, create a model, and then its one line to export the model into an `.mlmodel` file that you just drop in to xcode